# Regular expression which prevents certain characters and repeated characters

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a user input in my JSF application where the user

(1) should not enter their email address (that simply means the '@' character should not come there)

(2) should not enter their phone number (we may simply reject if the input contains minimum of 4 digit number input)

(3) should not keep on pressing the same button (we may reject if the input contains minimum of 4 repeated characters)

I need a regular expression to do the above validation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative lookahead assertions for this as:

```
^(?!.*@)(?!.*\d{4})(?!.*?(.)\1{3}).*$
```

[**Rubular link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/kIVa9dSzWE)

Answer (score 2):

I think here it's easiest to match based on what you can't accept rather than what you can.  The regex `@|\d{3}\d+|(.)\1{3}` is quite simple and easy to understand, and you can reject any input that that matches it.